# What is the subtle difference between condiment, seasoning and flavoring?

Tags: word-usage, differences

As far as I understand and definitions on Google go, all of these mean some "**substance to 'enhance' the flavor of food**." But what is the subtle difference in their meaning and word-usage?

Comment: A flavoring doesn't simply enhance flavor already present; it adds flavor of its own.

Comment: "Flavoring" is a generic term, meaning anything that modifies the flavor of the food.  The boundary between "condiment" and "seasoning" is fuzzy.

Answer (score 6):

A condiment is a food item that is added to food, usually on top of the food or one of its components, after it has been cooked. Examples include ketchup, mustard, mayonnaise, sauerkraut, banana pepper rings.

Seasoning is added to food before it has been fully cooked, in order to allow the cooking process to either integrate its flavor into the food or to cause it to change in some way that modifies its taste. Examples include spices such as thyme or coriander, sauces such as barbecue sauce or chili sauce, and vegetables such as jalapeño peppers or garlic.

Flavoring is a liquid, gel, or powder, derived either from natural or artificial sources, that gives food its base flavor. Examples include vanilla extract, rosewater, and almond extract.

Comment: no reference?  no source?

Comment: beautiful answer.

Comment: OK, so what is salt?  You can add it before and after cooking.

Comment: A very nice answer but  *chilli powder* is a spice, while *parsley*, *sage*, *rosemary* and *thyme* are **herbs**.